# Cassandra 3 legacy tables

Tags: cassandra

we are about to upgrade our cassandra infrastucture from v1.2 to 3.x, our schemas are with compact storage and we use thrift.
We tried successfully to use the support for legacy tables, and we were wondering where are the tradeoffs in terms of performance and functionality that might not be available as I am struggling to find specific documentation about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are upgrading from 1.2 to 3.x directly.I have seen people posting issues when you move directly.May be you want to first upgrade to some stable version in 2.x and from there to 3.x

Comment: yes we did 2.2, now unfortunately next step is to transfer data doesn't seem a way to convert from compact storage to normal cql, another problem we are facing is the thrift protocol which we need to abandon in favor of cql driver